# eslint no-restricted-syntax selector for private methodDefinition

Tags: eslint, abstract-syntax-tree, eslintrc

I use eslint on a TypeScript project and have some rule in **no-restricted-syntax config** that check naming for async method, like :

```json
{
  "selector": "MethodDefinition[value.async=true][key.name!=/Async$/]",
  "message": "Async method name must end in 'Async'"
}
```

I'm searching for something to **verify private function naming**. But I can't find a selector to select all private MethodDefinition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I found what I was searching for.

My answer was in [this documentation](https://typescript-eslint.io/docs/development/architecture/asts/) inside AST Playground part.

[The playground](https://typescript-eslint.io/play/#ts=4.6.2&sourceType=module&showAST=es&code=MYGwhgzhAEAuCmFbQN4FgBQ1vQA4CcBLANzAWgAt4QQB7AdVvxABMAKASlUx1+h5wBfTIKA) allow me to see all the node information usable in eslint.

[image]

And then I made my own rule to test private function naming (in my case, the name must start with an underscore) :

```json
{
  "selector": "MethodDefinition[accessibility=private][key.name!=/^_/]",
  "message": "Private function name must start with _"
}
```